# How to setup conditional merge to master on git

Tags: git, drone.io

My codebase is in git. how shall i setup conditional merge to master based on my drone build.
Merge option should be available only if the reviewer approve the pull request (which is happening now) and the drone build should be successful.

How / where shall i hook up in git to make sure the drone build is successful before enabling the merge to master option.

Comment: I would recommend using protected branches (see https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/). You can prevent code from being merged until all status checks pass (e.g. your drone build) and also require code review approval

Comment: I have made my master branch as protected. but it doesnt help me getting the drone build status check. Should i do anything else in web hooks or something like that

Comment: the status check is added automatically. If you don't see a status check that generally means `DRONE_HOST` was not properly configured and creating the status check is failing (which you would see in the drone server logs)